# Supporting Multiple Screens (2560X1600 and 1280x720)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have requirement to support all screen sizes on Android (Phones and Tablets). I have a set of images with resolutions 1280x720 and 2560x1600.

**Question**

How to name `drawable` and `layout` folders, so  that these images are scaled correctly for all resolutions(if possible) ?

I'm clear that the question has been asked very often, but all I can find are half answers. I tried to create drawable folders with names:

- `drawable-xlarge-mdpi` - for 1200X800
- `drawable-xlarge-xhdpi` - for 2560X1600

And for layout, with names:

- `layout-xlarge-mdpi` - for 1280x720
- `layout-xlarge-xhdpi` - for 25601600

And added a manifest entry:

```
   <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

But now, it works only for tablets. On phones it always fails with error.

I found an answer here:
[Drawables for qHD resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489784/drawables-for-qhd-resolution)

As I understand, all scaling occurs through code. But can anyone explain to me how to scale the image in the code with a resolution of 1280x720 and 2560x1600 and in which folder are to be placed in ?

I have read:

[Application Skeleton to support multiple screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen)

[Android : App support for multiple tablet screen resolutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633792/android-app-support-for-multiple-tablet-screen-resolutions)

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

[Android: support multiple screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380885/android-support-multiple-screens)

and many more.

Comment: i think this is work for you

check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728159/creating-multi-screen-support-app-android