# Creating multi-screen support app android

Tags: android, layout, screen, android-screen-support

I am creating a app in Android that must support multiple screens.

For this purpose i have read many answers and one which i like most is state that i can create  different folders in **res** folder by following name,

For small screens **layout-small**,

For large screens **layout-large**,

For extra large screens **layout-xlarge**

and i have to create different layouts for different screens with **same** name.
e.g mylayout.xml

and i have to put following code in manifest.xml file

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

and finally i just need to write following lines in my Activity file,

```
  setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
```

Now when i run this app in different size screens it should acquire layouts from different folders as per screen resolution.

But this is not happening in my case.It takes only layout that defined in **layout** folder.

Please can some one explains me why this happening and how can i solve this issue so that my app can run effectively on all size screens.

Comment: You have to copy the xml file to those folders

Comment: no i have created separate screens in each folder

Comment: if the screens are with same names? i.e. main.xml in each folder

Comment: then plaese try name like this  layout-sw320dp,layout-sw480dp,layout-sw600dp,layout-sw720dp

Comment: yes i have using same names

Comment: @JayVyas check this http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple screen support in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453982/multiple-screen-support-in-android)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Try out like:**

- layout-sw320dp
- layout-sw480dp
- layout-sw600dp
- layout-sw720dp

**instead of**

- layout-small,
- layout-large etc...

Comment: btw what should i try for drawable images ?

Comment: same way you can create try drawable-xxhdpi,drawable-sw-720dp etc. .

Comment: what if one folder supporting multiple screen ??

Answer (score 8):

Please refer below link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
For Different screen size, The following is a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for small, medium, high, and extra high density screens. you could use different size of the layout files in res folder and also vary for drawable images based on the density..

```
  res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
  res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
  res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
  res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
  res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

[image]
      res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
      res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
      res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />        
</compatible-screens>
```

And followed by any activity use this lines..

android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that many times a single layout xml will be fine, so you may only need just one layout folder. In that case you would still want different values folders for specific dimens / drawables / etc.  Referencing those resources from the single layout makes life much easier.

Comment: your approach is good but it's difficult to go through every folder and update the changes...Can we do through single folder like layout and layout-land for all the screens

Answer (score 4):

In values folder naming convention like `layout-small` only works for devices with `api version less than 3.1`. You should create values file with naming like `layout-sw600dp` for api level greater than 3.1. read this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html3.1api

[image]
like this you should create layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp for each type of devices.
layout-sw600dp means this layout works for devices with smallest width of 600dp
If you have layout-600dp and layout-sw720dp folders. first layout folder works for devices with smallest width of 600dp(7 inch tablet) to 720dp and second works for devices with smallest width above 720dp(10 inch tablet).

> If your minimum required version is above 3.1 you don't need have
>   layout-small, layoutxLarge folders. otherwise you have to consider
>   both type of layout fromats.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a quick checklist** about how you can ensure that your application displays properly on different screens:

Use `wrap_content, fill_parent,` or `dp` units when specifying dimensions in an XML layout file.
Do not use hard coded `pixel` values in your application code(`.java` files).
Do not use `AbsoluteLayout` (it's deprecated in `Android 1.5`). You should instead use `RelativeLayout`, which uses relative positioning to lay out its child views.
Supply alternative bitmap drawables for different screen densities.

Take time and read these [screens_support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) or to get a better idea see [How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) so that you know where to place your resources.