# Android general scaling for different devices

Tags: android, xml, scale

Goodmorning to you all.

I've got a question regarding the scaling of my application that I've recently started building.
I'm fairly to new to programming but even more new to Android development.

As you can see: my textviews work fine for a smaller resolution but don't scale for bigger resolutions.

[image: http://imgur.com/b5Ed3gh]

What would be a possible solution?

My XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"

    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="106dp"
        android:width="135dp"
        android:height="130dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:text="Start" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/topRight"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/startButton" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/topLeft"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/startButton" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/topLeft"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topLeft"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:width="135dp"
        android:height="130dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/topRight"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topRight"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:width="135dp"
        android:height="130dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/topLeft"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/topLeft"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:width="135dp"
        android:height="130dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/highscore"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create different layout folder for device like

layout-hdpi

layout-mdpi

layout-ldpi

layout-xdlpi and so one

[Look This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728159/creating-multi-screen-support-app-android)