# I can not display the same design on different phones(DialogFragment)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

I am have some problem with displaying design on different devices.
I am do not solve this problem.
This is photo - [enter link description here](https://pp.vk.me/c625126/v625126208/220e3/g61grWOdjbI.jpg)

This is xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#ffffffff">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="225.75dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ItemName"
                    android:id="@+id/itemName"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:paddingTop="14dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="14dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ItemPrice"
                    android:id="@+id/itemPrice"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingRight="14dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="161.75dp"
                android:id="@+id/itemImage"
                android:layout_weight="16"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Buy 1 and Get 2 for free "
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="25dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="101dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/placeholder_blue"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingTop="26dp"
            android:paddingBottom="26dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="49dp"
                android:layout_height="49dp"
                android:text="-"
                android:id="@+id/itemMinus"
                android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
                android:background="#fff"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="49dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="49dp"
                android:layout_height="49dp"
                android:text="+"
                android:id="@+id/itemPlus"
                android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
                android:background="#fff"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingTop="38.5dp"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="65.25dp"
            android:layout_height="65.25dp"
            android:id="@+id/itemCancel"
            android:src="@drawable/cancel"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="65.25dp"
            android:layout_height="65.25dp"
            android:id="@+id/itemAdd"
            android:src="@drawable/apply"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

On the photo left to right:

> ```
> LG g3 - 5" 1280 x 720 294 dpi
> samsung galaxy s5 - 5,1" 1080x1920 432 dpi
> samsung galaxy note 4 - 5.7" 1440x2560  515 dpi
> nexus 6 5.96" 1440x2560 493 dpi
> ```

the problem is that my DialogFragment displaying design on different devices. I need to make it always as the first phone (LG g3).

what am I doing wrong? I have 5 folders with pictures mdpi hdpi xhdpi xxhdpi xxxhdpi. I cut them a script in Photoshop. I checked the calculator. all the same. but still displayed crooked. I tried to use the values weight.

EDIT: All pictures displayed normal. But my DialogFragment displayed always at the center. I need to top-left corner DialogFragment was always under the button is on him and had no padding down

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating multi-screen support app android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728159/creating-multi-screen-support-app-android)

Answer (score 1):

Why not try mixing in RelativeLayout? If you use the layout_weight it really depends on the screen size and density from my understanding and if you use RelativeLayout maybe you could align them the way you want properly. Like using its center_horizontal="true", above="@id/x", below="@id/y".