# I am having problems with compatibility in android app

Tags: android

I am tired of this, I am a newbie in Android, and I made an app , but I face many problems with compatiblity, I don't know how to adjust every screen to my app, and how to make it work for api min 15.Right now it is 19 because I have many problems with lower API.

[Problem android Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVAp8.png)

So I decided to  make files like

res\layout
 res\layout-sw600dp
 res\layout-sw720dp

But, still it does not work in small screens, Can someone help me on this? How can I adjust to every screen or at least with. I will so happy if someone can help me.

Comment: what is your layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 3 ways to do this!

1. You can create multiple layout

   res\layout res\

   [See link on Google Developer](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)
   [See link on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728159/creating-multi-screen-support-app-android)
2. You can create multiple dimen

   [This is example on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860815/how-to-define-dimens-xml-for-every-different-screen-size-in-android)
3. using code

   - Create class ***SetViewSizeByPixel.class***

   This is code

public class SetViewSizeByPixel {

```
private LayoutParams params = null;
private DisplayMetrics metrics = null;
private Context mContext;
public static final int match_parent = -1;

public SetViewSizeByPixel(Context context) {
    metrics = getMetrics(context);
    this.mContext = context;
}

/**
 * 
 */

public int RH(int x) {
    return metrics.heightPixels * x / 1920;
}

public int RW(int x) {
    return metrics.widthPixels * x / 1080;
}

public int RH720p(int x) {
    return metrics.heightPixels * x / 1280;
}

public int RW720p(int x) {
    return metrics.widthPixels * x / 720;
}

public int RH(float x) {
    return (int) (metrics.heightPixels * x / 1920);
}

public int RW(float x) {
    return (int) (metrics.widthPixels * x / 1080);
}

/**
 * Metrics
 */

public DisplayMetrics getMetrics(Activity activity) {
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    return metrics;
}

public DisplayMetrics getMetrics(Context context) {
    return getMetrics((Activity) context);
}

public DisplayMetrics getMetrics() {
    return metrics;
}

public int heightPixels() {
    return metrics.heightPixels;
}

public int widthPixels() {
    return metrics.widthPixels;
}

public float density() {
    return metrics.density;
}

public int densityDpi() {
    return metrics.densityDpi;
}

/**
 * Size
 */

public boolean height(View view, int height) {
    return size(view, -1, height);
}

public boolean width(View view, int width) {
    return size(view, width, -1);
}

public boolean square(View view, int x) {
    return size(view, x, x);
}

public boolean size(View view, int width, int height) {
    try {
        params = view.getLayoutParams();
        if (width != -1)
            params.width = width;
        else
            params.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

        if (height != -1)
            params.height = height;
        else
            params.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SetSizeByPercent", e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Size with RW, RH.
 */

public boolean heightR(View view, int height) {
    return size(view, -1, this.RH(height));
}

public boolean widthR(View view, int width) {
    return size(view, this.RW(width), -1);
}

public boolean squareR(View view, int x) {
    return size(view, this.RW(x), this.RH(x));
}

public boolean sizeR(View view, int width, int height) {
    return size(view, RW(width), RH(height));
}

/**
 * Margin R
 */
public void marginTopR(View v, int top) {
    marginTop(v, RH(top));
}

public void marginR(View v, int lef, int top, int rig, int bot) {
    margin(v, RH(lef), RH(top), RH(rig), RH(bot));
}

public void marginR(View v, int x) {
    margin(v, RW(x), RH(x), RW(x), RH(x));
}

/**
 * Margin
 */
public void marginLeft(View v, int lef) {
    margin(v, lef, -1, -1, -1);
}

public void marginTop(View v, int top) {
    margin(v, -1, top, -1, -1);
}

public void marginRight(View v, int rig) {
    margin(v, -1, -1, rig, -1);
}

public void marginBottom(View v, int bot) {
    margin(v, -1, -1, -1, bot);
}

public void marginLeft(View v, int lef, boolean keepOldMargin) {
    int k = keepOldMargin ? -1 : 0;
    margin(v, lef, k, k, k);
}

public void marginTop(View v, int top, boolean keepOldMargin) {
    int k = keepOldMargin ? -1 : 0;
    margin(v, k, top, k, k);
}

public void marginRight(View v, int rig, boolean keepOldMargin) {
    int k = keepOldMargin ? -1 : 0;
    margin(v, k, k, rig, k);
}

public void marginBottom(View v, int bot, boolean keepOldMargin) {
    int k = keepOldMargin ? -1 : 0;
    margin(v, k, k, k, bot);
}

public void margin(View v, int margin) {
    margin(v, margin, margin, margin, margin);
}

public void margin(View v, int lef, int top, int rig, int bot) {
    if (v.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        lef = (lef == -1) ? p.leftMargin : lef;
        top = (top == -1) ? p.topMargin : top;
        rig = (rig == -1) ? p.rightMargin : rig;
        bot = (bot == -1) ? p.leftMargin : bot;

        p.setMargins(lef, top, rig, bot);
        v.requestLayout();
    }
}

public LayoutParams getParams() {
    return params;
}

public void setParams(LayoutParams params) {
    this.params = params;
}

/**
 * Text Size
 */
public void textSize(TextView tv, int size) {
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size);
}

public void textSize(View view, int size) {
    try {
        ((TextView) view).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", e.toString());
    }
}

public void textSizeR(TextView view, int size) {
    view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, RH(size));
}

public void textSizeR(View view, int size) {
    try {
        ((TextView) view).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, RH(size));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", e.toString());
    }
}

/**
 * Animation & TypeFace
 */
public Animation getAnimation(int id) {
    return AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, id);
}

public Typeface getTypeface(String typefacePath) {
    return Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), typefacePath);
}

// public void setSize(View v,int w,int h){
// float hrate = MyActivity.Height/1920f;
// size(v, (int) (w*hrate),(int)(h*hrate));
// }
  }
```

This is example

in onCreate()

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SetViewSizeByPixel setsize = new SetViewSizeByPixel(HighScoreActivity.this);
    DisplayMetrics metris = setsize.getMetrics(HighScoreActivity.this);

    // Main_Menu
    setsize.size(layout_header, metris.widthPixels * 1024 / 1024, metris.heightPixels * 60 / 600);
    layout_header.setPadding(metris.widthPixels * 10 / 1024, metris.heightPixels * 10 / 600,
            metris.widthPixels * 10 / 1024, metris.heightPixels * 10 / 600);
    setsize.textSize(txt_top, metris.widthPixels * 15 / 600);
    setsize.textSize(txt_time, metris.widthPixels * 15 / 600);
    setsize.textSize(txt_main_menu, metris.widthPixels * 15 / 600);
    setsize.size(txt_top, metris.widthPixels * 200 / 1024, metris.heightPixels * 40 / 600);
    setsize.size(txt_time, metris.widthPixels * 600 / 1024, metris.heightPixels * 40 / 600);
    setsize.size(txt_main_menu, metris.widthPixels * 204 / 1024, metris.heightPixels * 40 / 600);
```

Note:

- You just take screen device test. And use photoshop to show ficture.

  metris.widthPixels * 600 / 1024

  600 is 600px,  desired width is measured with the image in Photoshop
  1024 is 1024px, the width of the device screen test