# How to manage multiple screens with different density?

Tags: android, layout, android-screen-support

For supporting multiple screens we can define layouts as layout-sw360dp layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp etc, But for example for a device that chooses the **layout-sw360dp**, the device screen density can be of

```
 xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi
```

So should we have to define multiple dimens values as,

> #### values-sw360dp-xhdpi
>
> #### values-sw360dp-xxhdpi
>
> #### values-sw360dp-xxxhdpi
>
> Otherwise if I'm not giving values specifically for each densities, my layout will get broken for various devices with different densities.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating multi-screen support app android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728159/creating-multi-screen-support-app-android)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280277/different-values-folders-in-android

Answer (score 0):

For dimens you have to manage like this given below.

> **values-w600dp**
>
> **values-w720dp**
>
> **values-w820dp**
>
> **values-xhdpi**
>
> **values-xxhdpi**
>
> **values-xxxhdpi**