# Textview maxlines depends on its height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a textview which is its height depends on the size of height of imageview, and the image's width is 30% of screen size. I set the textview with maxlines=2 and ellipsize=end. It works good in Nexus S but not good in larger screen such us Nexus 7 because maxlines is keep 2 not larger. How to make maxlines larger depends on screen size?

**Nexus S**

[image: Nexus S]

**Nexus 7**

[image]

**And this is the code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nama"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/ivPhotoProfile"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUsername"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tvName"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/tvName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvName"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBio"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivPhotoProfile"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tvUsername"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/tvUsername"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvUsername"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPhotoProfile"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile_picture_default"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.30625"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: show us your xml file

Comment: I am using constraintlayout

Comment: add you xml file

Comment: sorry about that.. here it is

Comment: Relative layout is easy and better option for doing this.

Comment: have you learn about constraint layout?

Answer (score 2):

Try with to remove below line from `<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBio" ...` xml:-

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivPhotoProfile"
```

Comment: it's not about height of the view, but the maxlines of the text view

Answer (score 2):

Here is best solution for this problem that I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46904071/6476816

Worked for me, I had similar layout as you.

Answer (score 1):

For different Screen size you have to go for support multiple screens.

References :

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

[Creating multi-screen support app android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728159/creating-multi-screen-support-app-android)

http://mrbool.com/how-to-handle-multiple-screen-sizes-in-android/31291

Answer (score 1):

Don't set you **maxlines** just make your textview **android:ellipsize="end"** and align your textview bottom to imageview bottom it will automatically takes maxlines according to size of your textview and keep your textview aligned to your imageview

Comment: alignedToBottom of image view so that it will change accordingly to imageviews height.

Comment: if i don't set maxlines, then ellipsize doesn't work

Comment: Then try to do something like this : 
**
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:minLines="2"**
 in which maxlines are the lines you want to set on large devices