# Ellipsize text in TextView without specifying maxLines

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView whose height would vary based on the other components in the screen. I have a long text to be set in this TextView and hence I would like to ellipsize it. Simply specifying android:ellipsize="end" is not working. Only on specifying maxLines along with it, the ellipsizing works. But I cannot specify a value for maxLines since the height of TextView is dynamic. How do I get the text ellipsized without specifying maxLines for the TextView?

Comment: android:ellipsize="end" ,if I got you right

Comment: Simply specifying android:ellipsize="end" is not working. Only on specifying maxLines along with it, the ellipsizing works.

Comment: better append ... at the end or your string value

Comment: Share your xml code

Comment: @AnkitAman I can't do that since I wouldn't know where exactly I need to append ...

Comment: @sushantgosavi Here it is https://www.dropbox.com/s/v4b19h8vonnjonu/ellipsize_not_working.xml?dl=0

Comment: Why the downvote? Is it not a valid question?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem by adding global layout listener.
Following is the code snippet

```
tvDesc.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            tvDesc.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            int noOfLinesVisible = tvDesc.getHeight() / tvDesc.getLineHeight();

            tvDesc.setText(R.string.desc);

            tvDesc.setMaxLines(noOfLinesVisible);
            tvDesc.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Solution works, I just wanted to add that you have to remove `android:ellipsize="end"` in the layout xml to make it work.